# Why does the last row of the table have a bigger height than the rest?

Tags: html, css

On this page http://church.allthingswebdesign.com/Calendar.php the last row of the table is bigger than the rest of the rows.

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the last four cells (wednesday to saturday) is empty.
To check, put some number there and the height will be ok.

To fix, edit file *styles.css*, line 240.

Change the rule `tbody tr td`, adding `vertical-align: bottom` (to overwrite `vertical-align: baseline` that cames from *reset.css*)

The new css rule will be:

```
tbody tr td {
    border:1px solid #3A3939;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    max-width:13%;
    width:13%;
    vertical-align:bottom;   
}
```

Comment: I just ended up putting &nbsp; in each td.